# LibreOffice writer - how to use a particular font size in Paragraph Style (8.5 pt)

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

I need to give 8.5 pt to the font of my default paragraph style. The UI is coded with a fixed list of font sizes, it appears:

[image]

So I don't want 8 pt, I don't want 9 pt, I want 8.5 pt. How do I get that?

LibreOffice version is 5.2.7.2 (Debian Stretch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click in the text box under *Size* and type in a new value.  Then click somewhere outside the box or press Enter.

[image: edit paragraph style]

This screenshot is from LO 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu xenial.

Answer (score 0):

A trick that seems to work is, with the current document open, to go to *Tools* > *Options* > *LibreOffice Writer* > *Basic Fonts (Western)*. This shows the *currently used fonts* of the document. In default style, you can then enter a custom size such as 8.5 pt, which then subsequently seems to be used in the document.